# Centering item along several nodes in bmatrix

Tags: positioning, amsmath, matrices

How can I position `X` exactly in the middle of space between `a` and `d` column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d & e \\
                a & b & c & d & e \\
                  &   & X &   & e
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

`bmatrix` uses a normal `array` internally so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c & d & e      \\
                a & b & c & d & e      \\
                  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{X} &   & e
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

As noted in the comments `\multicolumn{4}{c}{X} & e` is another possibility, depending on where exactly you want to centre. This image shows the two versions with a modified matrix making the columns widths of a and d more distinct.

[image]

Comment: The last row may be also `\multicolumn{4}{c}{X} & e`

Comment: Yes it's hard to see the difference in this example, but if a and  d columns are different widths, my version centers on the inner edges, whereas @egreg's centers on the outer edges, so taking the widths of the a and d column into account. Take your pick:-)